# Protege unexpected close results in 'owl:' prefix when the ontology is reopened

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, prefix, protege

I am working on an ontology. Suddenly, Protege closes unexpectedly. When I reopen it and open the last ontology I notice that all my classes, individuals and properties are now renamed with the prefix 'owl:'. With this my SPARQL queries no longer work. So far I've worked around it by opening an older version of the same ontology but it's a pain to manually update the old one to the new one because I simply can't find how to remove this prefix. Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a crash/bug in the desktop Protege app, which would probably be better raised to the [development project](https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues).

Comment: To fix your data, you should be able to open the file in a text editor and do a search/replace - faster than renaming things manually in Protege.

Comment: yeah I tried this - renaming it all. The file still opens with the owl prefix in protege though and I can't import it into another ontology editor because it can't be parsed. very sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by saving the file as RDF/XML. I was using Turtle format when the issue occurred.